# Dropdown moving up after selecting an option in IE11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11

I am facing an issue with select tag in IE11. It has a long list of options and when I select an option and open the list the second time the entire list is moving up,if the option selected is in the bottom of the list, the list is moving out of the window.

[image]

Sample code available [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KQ4Fp0z1Te3mzD0fctdvRm3gGhCZ4ueL/view).

How to restrict drop down to going up in IE11?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website OR off-site example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to style the option of an html "select" element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-an-html-select-element)

Comment: No @asimovwasright

Comment: I tried to make a test with your sample code in IE 11, Windows 10 OS and I found that it is working fine and issue is not producible. Can you please inform us, which OS you are using on your side? I suggest you to check for the latest updates for your Windows OS and install it. then again try to make a test. Let us know about your testing results.

Answer (score 0):

It's just the way IE (Windows) renders select boxes, which are OS dependant components.

I would suggest using a framework suggested in the question I referenced in my comment: 
[How to style the option of an html "select" element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-an-html-select-element)

You're never going to stop IE from doing this, as annoying as it is ;-)